# Toggle Desktop Through Hotcorners

Tags: unity-tweak-tool

I am trying to toggle the desktop by going to the lower left corner. I used the Hotcorners from the Unity Tweak Tool by setting that corner to "Toggle Desktop" but it doesn't work. The other functions for that corner work as they should though. Why is that happening?

If you have any other alternatives to succeed that feel free to mention them.

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. I tired every position (top, bottom, sides, corners etc.) with no success.